# Turn on and off the IDENTITY_INSERT before and after insert dynamically

Tags: sql-server

```
select 
    row_number() over (order by 1) as rn, * 
into 
    #execute_insert 
from 
    #finaldata 
where 
    noofrows > 0;

declare @intmin int, @intmax int

select @intmin = min(rn), max(rn) 
from #execute_insert

begin
    declare @query nvarchar(max) ='';

    select @query = concat('ALTER TABLE ' + table_Name + 'NOCHECK CONSTRAINT All ') 

    If set Identity_Insert ON 
        select @query = 'insert Into' + @Table_Name + ' '+ @column_Name 
                       +' select ' + @Column_Name 
                       +' from '+@Table_Name+' '+ sql_query+'' 
    Else Identity_insert Off
end
```

Comment: no, this is not possible

Comment: What's the point of this code? What are you trying to do and why would a *database setting* affect what should or shouldn't go into a table?

Comment: BTW you don't need to call `CONCAT` with a single argument when you *already* concatenated the strings. `SET Identity_Insert ON` is a statement, not an expression and can't be used in `IF`. You can't use `IDENTITY_INSERT` by itself the way you do in the `ELSE` branch. Whatever it is you're trying to do there are far easier ways to do it

Comment: the question is how i need to set identity_insert on before insertion and off after insertion followed by an if condition. i just want to know what is the correct way of writing so. @DaleBurrell

Comment: I just learned that concat is not necessary. Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @sashank you wrote that in the title already and it still doens't explain what the problem is. If you check [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) you see that you need to specify the table name.  The code posted won't work for a *lot* of reasons, not just the missing table

Comment: @sashank what are you trying to do? Toggling IDENTITY_INSERT is what you think the solution is, not the actual problem. Why would you need to toggle `IDENTITY_INSERT` like that? In a migration script or initialization script you can simply use the table names. If you need to toggle IDENTITY_INSERT in production because you want to insert data with hard-coded IDs, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @sashank for example you could use [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-2017) to generate incrementing IDs instead of `IDENTITY` and use [NEXT VALUE FOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as a default value for the ID field. This would allow you to insert ID values as long as they don't conflict with the sequence's range.

Comment: @sashank please [edit] your question and add the actual question - rather than putting in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to toggle your `Identity_Insert` in SQL. However you may achieve the same by using `dynamic sql`. Everytime when you are inserting some data in a table, set `Identity_Insert ON` for that table and `close` it after executing your query.

You can make both `ON` and `OFF` in one command, to make sure that it is always in closed state after execution of query.

```
.
.
.
-- your code

SET @query = 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @Table_Name + ' ON '
SET @query = @query + ' insert Into' + @Table_Name + ' '+ @column_Name 
                       +' select ' + @Column_Name 
                       +' from '+@Table_Name+' '+ sql_query+''
SET @query = @query + ' SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @Table_Name + ' OFF '
EXEC (@query )
.
.
.
```

Note: I am not checking your query, hope that works fine individually, this is example to set `IDENTITY_INSERT` `ON` and `OFF` in single query statement.

Comment: @sashank what's the *actual* problem? You shouldn't have to toggle IDENTITY_INSERT at all. There are ways you can generate incrementing values *and* inserting specific IDs without using `IDENTITY`

Comment: What i wanted to do was insert data from one one database to another database having same table. So im using Identity_insert. I thought this is a way to do that. so trying it. @PanagiotisKanavos just wanted to know the way to use it. Like in the example that DarkRob mentioned.

Comment: @sashank that won't help you - you'll end up with duplicate IDs. Which I suspect you already found out, hence that `NOCHECK`. Once you turn IDENTITY back you you'll *still* get duplicates for any new rows.

Comment: So, Is using Sequence a better option than identity_insert in this case. I'm new to DB. So I'm just exploring things. It would be really helpful if you just guide me through.  @PanagiotisKanavos.

Comment: @sashank: as you said you are copying data from one table to another table so kind of making identical record with respect to base table, if you insert some new id then it is difficult to trace your record again. If there are some relationship maintained then you may loose that part. So you need to first decide whether you want to post identical records or you are creating new record on basis of old records.

Comment: I'm  just posting the identical records. but in future I might add new records into those tables. @DarkRob. So what should i use instead of  Identity_insert

Comment: identity_insert is fine for you, just make sure that previous record are maintaining unique id.

Comment: If the tires are indeed identical, you don't need an identity column in the destination take. As for inserting rows there that don't come from the other table, a sequence would work fine. Just be sure to have the sequence generate from a separate range!